# Android Dynamic (BasicNameValuePair)

Tags: php, android, sqlite

Stored a username in my android SQLite Database, When sending a request to a PHP server I want to use the value in the database.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("surename","$u"));
```

I want to "$u" to be whatever the value is on my database.

*so I added this:*

```
Cursor u = mdbhelper.rawQuery();
```

And in my database helper:

```
 public Cursor rawQuery() {
return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] {KEY_USER}, null, null, null,  null, null);
}
```

But it is not working.
*Based on:* 
http://android10.org/index.php/articlesdatastorage/97-connecting-to-mysql-database

Can anyone help with this please.

Log CAT:

```
01-11 17:02:56.670: E/AndroidRuntime(8924): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{co.uk.RAA/co.uk.RAA.PhpWrequest}: java.lang.NullPointerException

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at co.uk.RAASoulutions.PhpWrequest.<init>(PhpWrequest.java:63)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)

01-11 17:02:56.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
```

When you follow the link it show the php file and project I am trying to modify.

When I say not working, I get an error on the tablet (Force to close).
If I put a valid value in ($u) then it returns the data in the screen, but I am trying to read it from the Android database (Dynamic value) instead of (Static value).

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: "it is not working" please add more details (exception, LogCat, etc.)

Comment: Why is this question tagged 'php'? I don't see anything here that has to do with php other than the index.php in the url :)

Comment: I added the Log and more code. I need to send a value to the PHP server.  That value is saved in the android databse. I need to get a cursor query and the result needs to be eg. a string or a KEY that I can user later.  Think of it as saving your username and password in your local database and then when sending it to the php server you can use the query result usernmae = KEY_1, password = KEY_2,